# how to get the number of profile views

Tags: support, api-v2

according to the [documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user), a `User` object has an attribute `view_count`, indicating the number of views of the user's profile. An example is also given there. However, when I sent a request
`/2.0/users/1?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow` I got the following returned. Where is `view_count`?

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "user_id": 1,
      "user_type": "moderator",
      "creation_date": 1217514151,
      "display_name": "Jeff Atwood",
      "profile_image": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/51d623f33f8b83095db84ff35e15dbe8?d=identicon&r=PG",
      "reputation": 21911,
      "reputation_change_day": 20,
      "reputation_change_week": 73,
      "reputation_change_month": 98,
      "reputation_change_quarter": 528,
      "reputation_change_year": 3122,
      "age": 41,
      "last_access_date": 1344378892,
      "last_modified_date": 1344439260,
      "is_employee": true,
      "link": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood",
      "website_url": "http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/",
      "location": "El Cerrito, CA",
      "account_id": 1,
      "badge_counts": {
        "gold": 29,
        "silver": 97,
        "bronze": 111
      },
      "accept_rate": 100
    }
  ],
  "quota_remaining": 9985,
  "quota_max": 10000,
  "has_more": false
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View count is not returned by default (see the list of default fields [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user)). It's excluded in the default filter.

Try adding this: `&filter=!9hnGsu7zN`

**EDIT:**

The filters can be generated using the API's filter create method https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-filter.

Or manually using the 'default filter [edit]' drop down found on each method's docs page.

Comment: Great! And how to use other non-default filters, such as about_me or up_vote_count?